# My code is giving the correct output but Leetcode keep saying that the output is not the expected

Tags: c, algorithm, backtracking

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int *count_op;
int k = 0;

void backTrack(int *nums, int numsSize, int x, int i, int j, int counter)
{
    if (x == 0)
    {
        count_op[k++] = counter;
        return ;
    }
    else if (x < 0)
    {
        return ;
    }
    if (i < numsSize && j >= 0)
    {
        backTrack(nums, numsSize, x - nums[i], i + 1, j, counter + 1);
        backTrack(nums, numsSize, x - nums[j], i, j - 1, counter + 1);
    }
}

int minOperations(int* nums, int numsSize, int x)
{
    int z = 0;
    int min = -1;
    while (z < numsSize)
    {
        if (nums[z] < 1 || nums[z] > pow(10,4))
            return (-1);
        z++;
    }
    z = 0;
    if (numsSize >= 1 && numsSize <= pow(10,5) && x >= 1 && x <= pow(10,9))
    {
        count_op = malloc(sizeof(int) * pow(2, numsSize - 1));
        while (z < numsSize)
        {
            count_op[z] = -1;
            z++;
        }
        backTrack(nums, numsSize, x, 0, numsSize - 1, 0);
        min = count_op[0];
        z = 0;
        while (z < numsSize && count_op[z] > 0)
        {
            if (min > count_op[z])
                min = count_op[z];
            z++;
        }
    }
    return (min);
}

int main(void)
{
    int nums[] = {3,2,20,1,1,3};
    int min = minOperations(nums, 6, 10);
    printf("%d\n", min);
}
```

[Here is the problem I'm trying to solve, and what Leetcode is saying that the output is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gw2F.png)
...
[Here is the output when I run it in VS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIzlK.png)
...
[Here is the output when I run it on an online compiler(GDB)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuXhz.png)

I don't know what to try honestly, I'm still a beginner and this is my first time using Leetcode, so I don't know what to do!!
I don't even know if it is appropreate to ask these kind of questions here or not...
I would apprecieate any help

Comment: Please post a description of the problem as text, not a link to Leetcode.

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize `k` to 0 each run.

In Leet, it runs multiple cases reusing your function (`minOperations`) each test case (without reloading program) so global data remains intact between test cases.

Your code fails on what Leet considers to be practice test case 3.

This means `k` is set on entry to whatever the prior testcase left it as.  This has a negative effect on your algorithm.

So on case 2 its initially 4 (correctly return -1 and does not effect `k` or depend on k) and on 3 continues to initially be 4 and fails.

So to fix:

```
int minOperations(int* nums, int numsSize, int x)
{
    k = 0;
    //... rest of code.
```

This then explains why running your `main` test driver once on "case 3" inputs works since its the first run and k=0.

NOTE: Leet has a console output and you can put in printfs without effecting the return result and verification.  So prior to fixing you could add:

```
   int minOperations(int* nums, int numsSize, int x)
   {
      printf("k=%d\n", k);
      ...
```

and observe the problem in the 'stdout' section in the console for case 3.

---

Now the bad news:

After fixing your problem as stated above, when you "submit" you'll discover yet another test case which fails with "heap buffer overflow" (there's a total of 94 test cases you must get through and this occurs on 5 not counting the 3 "practice" cases.  That may be your next post.